# How do I php query regex on a mongodb Date

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, timestamp, mongodate

I have a collection of users and i want to get all the users who registered in 2015.

With a normal date string it is possible tot query:

```
$query=[
    'timestamp'=> [
       '$regex' => "2015"
    ]
];
```

But when I try this on a MongDate timestamp it doens't work anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: you want mangodb query?

Answer (score 1):

A date stored in MongoDB is not a string, it's a date type. You cannot match regular expressions against it because it is not a string. Instead, just search with a date range (and index the date field, if you want it to be fast):

```
db.test.find({ "timestamp" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), "$lt" : ISODate("2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z") } })
```

I'm not familiar with PHP so I wrote the query in mongo shell syntax.

Comment: needs an upvote, makes sense you can't regex over a date object, so the next best thing you can do is use $gte $lt operators